# How to pass dotnet tools in to a docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, sonarqube

On root I used :
`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 4.7.1`to install sonarscanner
and it's working:

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.7.1
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
WARNING: Please specify the command 'begin' or 'end' to indicate whether pre- or post-processing is required. These parameters will become mandatory in a later release.
Post-processing started.
```

But in a docker it isn't:

```
root@3bea636a6418:/# dotnet sonarscanner
bash: dotnet: command not found
```

I tried to pass it:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

but with no luck

ps. ...and everything because of sonarscanner could not find java on docker:

````
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.2
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
Calling the SonarScanner CLI…
Could not find ‘java’ executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
14:43:39.402 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1```
````

Comment: A docker container can be considered a 'clean' system. It only has what you install in the container. Generally, you should be installing whatever dependencies you need in the container before you try to execute the sonarscanner (in this case, you would need to install dotnet & possibly java). What is your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install all the dependencies for your dotnet tools to work, `ldd` command can help you with this, and make sure all software required can be found also, for example can be found on the `PATH` variable if required.

to help you use interactive bash on the docker container, and add to your dockerfile if this works.
`docker exec -it (container) bash`

docker images usually installs what is required only, so you add the tools only to run your software successfully.

Comment: The problem is because in docker there is java but when CI/CD use this docker java don't work.

Comment: When you run `java -version` what do you get, if java is not found you either need to install this, or create your `JAVA_HOME` variable, and add this to your `PATH` environment variable also.

Comment: I added lines to install java and now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install --yes openjdk-11-jre
```

solved problem

ps. it's not that obvious because in docker bash when I run  `java -version` I get answer that java is already installed

Comment: most likely a jre is installed and the dotnet-sonarscanner requires a jdk.

Comment: in docker bash:

 java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)